# Show text on other activity than the button clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

I know how to show text with a button click on the same page, but my question is (since I couldn't find anything on Google): Is it possible when you click a button, that the text shows up on another activity?

Comment: Show text in the sense what? Do you wanna use `Toast` or setting a text on `TextView` or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I want to show it in a TextView

Comment: Still, Do you want to set it in Next `Activity` or the previous one?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can

In your `FirstActivity` execute this when button is clicked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data","Messsage to be sent");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your `SecondActivity` inside `onCreate()`:

```
String someData = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
yourTextView.setText(someData);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "yourTextView"? Because I can't get it working

Comment: "yourTextView" is TextView Object. Replace "yourTextView" with TextView you have created in your activity.

Comment: ah thanks! but the setText says it is a non static method. How can I solve this?

Comment: String someData = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
        TextView.setText(someData);

Comment: setText says it is a non static method

Comment: @Victor you cannot set the text to TextView you will have to create an object of it. TextView myTextView ;

Comment: After you have created an object "myTextView". then you have to findViewById(); after that, you can set Text to it. like : myTextView.setText("Hello World");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent` for this. `Intent` is used to move on other activity from first activity.

You can use :

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("YourValueKey", yourData.getText().toString());
```

then you can get it from your second activity by :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String YourtransferredData = intent.getExtras().getString("YourValueKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need pass values between the activities you use this:

```
 String name="aaaa";
 Intent intent=new Intent(Main_Activity.this,Other_Activity.class);
 intent.putExtra("name", name);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And this code to recovery data on new Activity:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = b.getString("name");
```